# Unity crashes unexpectedly, no option for recovery

Tags: 14.04, server, xorg, session, kill

Sometimes my Unity session crashes just like that - no window decorations, no panel, but whatever was going on in the background continues, like music playback. Problem is though it cannot be restarted, since the option to kill the X server has been removed from 14.04.

I tried to bind the "sudo service lightdm restart" to a shortcut, to no avail. I also tried to restart Unity by typing "unity", "unity --replace", I tried also "compiz --replace" in the TTY session, nothing worked.

**My hardware:**

`System:   Kernel: 3.13.0-39-generic x86_64 (64 bit) 
           Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:   System: TOSHIBA (portable) product: Satellite L650 version: PSK1EE-00Y007SK
           Mobo: TOSHIBA model: Portable PC Bios: INSYDE version: 2.40 date: 11/09/2011
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3 CPU M 330 (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 933.00 MHz 2: 933.00 MHz 3: 1999.00 MHz 4: 2133.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller 
           X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ironlake Mobile GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 10.2.2
Audio:     Card: Intel 5 Series/3400 Series High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA ver: k3.13.0-39-generic
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1500.3GB (35.3% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: Hitachi_HTS54505 size: 500.1GB 
           2: USB id: /dev/sdb model: CH11 size: 1000.2GB 
Partition: ID: / size: 46G used: 9.2G (22%) fs: ext4 ID: /home size: 409G used: 106G (28%) fs: ext4 
           ID: swap-1 size: 4.09GB used: 0.01GB (0%) fs: swap 
RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 53.0C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A 
Info:      Processes: 228 Uptime: 11:52 Memory: 1642.5/3753.0MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 1.9.17`

Answer (score 0):

For console use `CTRL+ALT+F1` (back to GUI use `CTRL+ALT+F7`)

Did you use Compiz Config with extra plugins or effects?

If yes, try this: `dconf reset -f /org/compiz` (**this will reset your Compiz settings**)

and this: `setsid unity` (**it's creates a session and sets the process group ID**)

Compiz Config can mess up, I don't know why, perhaps integrated graphic cards(?)
I had those problems too, I remember that only one cure for that kind of problem is reset compiz settings and configure them again with caution.

Comment: You got that right. I've installed CCSM and enabled additional effects/modified a few things, like the zoom control by mouse, fade in/out window effects and yer, I am using an integrated Intel HD Graphics Chipset 3000.

What exactly does `dconf reset -f /org/compiz` do?

Comment: it will reset your Compiz settings unfortunately

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this should I get that glitch again and post here the results of the above.

Comment: It's not necessary. Later, I'll try to get this glitch on my computer and using `strace -Ff -tt -p <PID> 2>&1 | tee strace-log.log` I'll try to track that bug. Maybe something will show what is a cause of that glitch

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul. Thing is, when I did what you suggested it reset Compiz but the settings remained, all but the snapping of windows into corners, that got disabled, at least from what I noticed, so it might be related to that.

Comment: Happened yesterday again after a fresh install and not using any additional Compiz plugins. I was running Virtualbox with XP in it and Adobe, minimized the VM to go and look up a folder via the Dash, the computer slowed down and the whole session crashed. Recovery was impossible. I am running Unity on a Toshiba Satellite L650 C13 laptop (4 years old) with an Intel Ironlake Mobile chipset, Intel Core i3 CPU and 4 GB DDR3 RAM. Is it perhaps that my laptop might not be powerful enough to run Unity and I should go with something else instead, like Xubuntu/Lubuntu?